# ARIBA - ServerThread.run() caught an exception while running ariba.base.tool.checkmeta.CheckMeta. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jvm, sap-ariba

We are getting below error while trying to connect to DB2 system.

> ServerThread.run() caught an exception while running ariba.base.tool.checkmeta.CheckMeta.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Please see more details from the log.

```
Wed Sep 13 12:29:55 BST 2017 () (startup.base:INFO) [ID9393]: Base phase     start 'Purge shared temp diretory'
Wed Sep 13 12:29:55 BST 2017 () (startup.base:INFO) [ID9394]: Base phase     stop 'Purge shared temp diretory' (trial #1) duration=0.0s - Mem. in KB:     44858->44858 (0)
Wed Sep 13 12:29:55 BST 2017 () (startup.base:INFO) [ID9393]: Base phase     start 'Init BaseService'
Wed Sep 13 12:29:55 BST 2017 () (startup.base:INFO) [ID9394]: Base phase     stop 'Init BaseService' (trial #1) duration=0.0s - Mem. in KB: 44856->44728     (128)
Wed Sep 13 12:29:55 BST 2017 () (startup.base:INFO) [ID9393]: Base phase     start 'Verify database connectivity'
Wed Sep 13 12:29:56 BST 2017 () (sqlio:WARN) [ID3960]: Expecting JDBC     Driver : [09.01.0000]. Getting JDBC Driver: 09.07.0011
Wed Sep 13 12:29:56 BST 2017 () (sqlio:WARN) [ID3961]: The JDBC Driver is     the Wrong Version.
Wed Sep 13 12:29:56 BST 2017 () (util:WARN) [ID2886]: ServerThread.run()     caught an exception while running ariba.base.tool.checkmeta.CheckMeta.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ariba.base.server.BaseServer.run(BaseServer.java:7 93)
at ariba.base.server.SimpleBaseServer.run(SimpleBaseS erver.java:137)
at ariba.base.tool.checkmeta.CheckMeta.run(CheckMeta. java:146)
at ariba.rpc.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.jav a:479)
at ariba.base.server.ObjectServerThread.run(ObjectSer verThread.java:488)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)

Wed Sep 13 12:29:56 BST 2017 () (util:WARN) [ID2935]: Server shutting     down with exit code: 1. Shutdown message: Problem on main server thread:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ariba.base.server.BaseServer.run(BaseServer.java:7 93)
at ariba.base.server.SimpleBaseServer.run(SimpleBaseS erver.java:137)
at ariba.base.tool.checkmeta.CheckMeta.run(CheckMeta. java:146)
at ariba.rpc.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.jav a:479)
at ariba.base.server.ObjectServerThread.run(ObjectSer verThread.java:488)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
(NodesDefault)
Wed Sep 13 12:29:57 BST 2017 () (org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK:WARN)
```

Comment: Besides the NPE it also says _The JDBC Driver is the Wrong Version._

Comment: Thanks Luciano.
Tried to convince the Team Lead (as I am just functional) and they say that this has got nothing to do with that.
Would you know what are the ill-effects of JDBC Driver in wrong version?